# ReactiveObjc - Trouble with throttle operator

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-programming

when using a throttle operator on a signal created by +createSignal function, I get a weird result:

```
    RACSignal* signal = [RACSignal createSignal:^RACDisposable *(id<RACSubscriber> subscriber) {


    [subscriber sendNext:@"1"];

    [subscriber sendNext:@"2"];

    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:4];

    [subscriber sendNext:@"3"];

    [subscriber sendNext:@"4"];

    [subscriber sendCompleted];
    return nil;
}];

[[[signal subscribeOn:[RACScheduler scheduler]] throttle:3] subscribeNext:^(id data) {
    NSLog(@"onNext: %@", data);
} completed:^{
    NSLog(@"Completed");
}];
```

what is expected according to the goal of the operator(Send nexts only if we don't receive another next in window interval, and if, another value is received before the window expires, the previous value is rejected and the window restarts for the next value) is:

```
onNext: 2
Completed
```

and the actual result is:

```
onNext: 4
Completed
```

Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just notice the presence of "subscribeOn" which must be replaced by "deliverOn" to not block the thread by the sleep.